# find time slots with sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a scenario (SQL 2008) where I need to find the occupied timeframes /non-gaps from the below table. For e.g . I have created this dummy table.

```
CREATE TABLE Job
(
JobID INT NOT NULL,
  WorkerID INT NOT NULL,
  JobStart DATETIME NOT NULL,
  JobEnd DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Job (JobID, WorkerID, JobStart, JobEnd)
    VALUES (1, 25, '2012-11-17 16:00', '2012-11-17 17:00'),
        (2, 25, '2012-11-17 16:00', '2012-11-17 16:50'),
        (3, 25, '2012-11-19 18:00', '2012-11-19 18:30'),
        (4, 25, '2012-11-19 17:30', '2012-11-19 18:10'),
        (5, 26, '2012-11-18 16:00', '2012-11-18 17:10'),
        (6, 26, '2012-11-18 16:00', '2012-11-19 16:50');
```

so for this , the qry shd return data like this:

```
WorkerID | StartDate | EndDate
25      2012-11-17 16:00   2012-11-17 17:00
25      2012-11-17 17:30   2012-11-17 18:30
26      2012-11-18 16:00    2012-11-18 17:10
```

I am able to get the result but I am using while loop and its a pretty iterative method. Any chance , I can avoid using while to get the result

Comment: there have been quite a few similar questions on SO.....

Comment: Should `EndDate` for `WorkerId` = 26 be `2012-11-19 16:50`?

Comment: yes @wewesthemennace, that was a typo :( it shd be 2012-11-19 16:50 for worker id 26

Answer (score 4):

This is a [**Packing Date and Time Interval**](http://sqlmag.com/blog/tsql-challenge-packing-date-and-time-intervals) problem. Itzik Ben-Gan has published an [**article**](http://sqlmag.com/blog/solutions-packing-date-and-time-intervals-puzzle) that provides many solutions to this problem. Using one of Itzik's solution, here is a query to solve your problem:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c0d89/1/0)

```
WITH C1 AS(
    SELECT
        JobID, WorkerId, JobStart AS ts, +1 AS type, NULL AS e,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY WorkerId ORDER BY JobStart, JobId) AS s
    FROM Job
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        JobID, WorkerId, JobEnd AS ts, -1 AS type,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY WorkerId ORDER BY JobEnd, JobId) AS e,
        NULL AS s
    FROM Job
),
C2 AS(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY WorkerId ORDER BY ts, type DESC, JobId) AS se
    FROM C1
),
C3 AS(
    SELECT ts, WorkerId,
        FLOOR((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY WorkerId ORDER BY ts) - 1) / 2 + 1) AS grpnum
    FROM C2
    WHERE COALESCE(s - (se - s) - 1, (se - e) - e) = 0
)
SELECT 
    WorkerId,
    MIN(ts) AS StartDate,
    MAX(ts) AS EndDate
FROM C3
GROUP BY WorkerID, grpnum
ORDER BY WorkerID
```

**Result**

```
WorkerId    StartDate               EndDate
----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
25          2012-11-17 16:00:00.000 2012-11-17 17:00:00.000
25          2012-11-19 17:30:00.000 2012-11-19 18:30:00.000
26          2012-11-18 16:00:00.000 2012-11-19 16:50:00.000
```

Comment: I have 1 more scenario.. can you pls help me on that too...

I have 1 table which contains Job starttime & job end time.. and another table which holds user entries ..This also has Shiftstarttime , Shiftendtime among other columns . This will be entered for future dates also..

While I adding a new record for user , I will have to check whether the Desired Start & Desired End time clashes with his entries as well as the JOb starttime + endtime or not... I have the queries ready but I have used while loop which I assume is not good wrt performance..

Any ideas are appreciated..

Comment: @XanderKage, I suggest you ask a new question so that it will attract more attention from the users.